# unable to start ./spark-shell

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, ubuntu-16.04

i am new to spark an dtrying to install spark on my ubuntu machine and
i am facing below error when am i trying to start spark -shell
please help

```
Caused by: org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException: Directory    /home/amar/spark-2.2.0-bin-hadoop2.7/bin/metastore_db cannot be created.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at    org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService$10.run(Unknown  Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at  org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.StorageFactoryService.createServiceRoot(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.bootService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.BaseMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.services.monitor.FileMonitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.iapi.services.monitor.Monitor.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection$5.run(Unknown Source)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedConnection.createPersistentService(Unknown Source)
... 149 more
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
   import spark.implicits._
          ^
<console>:14: error: not found: value spark
   import spark.sql
          ^
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.2.0
    /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

Comment: your hive meta store is a problem

Comment: How do you start the `spark-shell`?

Comment: using  ./spark-shell

Answer (score 0):

In my case the problem was in permissions. I was trying to launch spark as not admin user. 
 Once I've started as root, all went well. However I'm not recommending such behavior. Just pointing to check permissions and set it up accordingly. Running as root is a bad practice.